# Can one file a legal claim against a person in the Netherlands without knowing their address?

Tags: netherlands

Is it possible to file a legal claim against an individual in the Netherlands without knowing their home address?

In this particular case, all the following are known:

- the individual's name
- town of residence
- previous address in the Netherlands
- address abroad
- ... and more

- but not their current full address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

Providing you can tell the [gerechtsdeurwaarder](https://www.blenheim.nl/blog/serving-legal-documents-Netherlands) how to find them.

Service of the Dutch equivalent of a Statement of Claim can be done in person but only by the gerechtsdeurwaarder. If you know where they work, or what bus they catch or where they drink their coffee then you don’t need a residential address to find and serve them.